# How to color code a hostname from bash or python?

Tags: hash, text-coloring

I am looking for a simple solution that would give me a RGB color for each hostname.

I plan to use this for setting the tab-color in iTerm2, so I can easily spot the correct host based on the the color picket for it.

Now, I cannot use all 3-bytes because in some cases the differences can be too subtile, and also because I need to ban too dark to too light color.

Bases on this I can only assume that I could safely use 5 bits for each color, this would give me something like 2^15 = 128 colors to pick from. I can take care of the formula for converting the number to R,G,B values ;)

So what I need is a simple piece of code that would give me a 15 bit hash of a string (hostname).

If this would be doable in bash, it would be perfect, but I also accept a Python variant.

The solution has to work on Debian, RedHat and OS X without having to install additional utils or libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
MD5="md5sum"
if [[ $OS == 'darwin' ]]; then MD5="md5" ; fi
HASH=`hostname -s | ${MD5}`
echo -n -e     "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$((0x${HASH:0:2}))\a\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$((0x${HASH:2:2}))\a\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$((0x${HASH:4:2}))\a"
```

Comment: could you write an explanation of the final echo string and what it all means? thanks in advance

Comment: Mainly it does set the RGB values based on the value of the hash of the hostname. Considering that we have 3*2^256 colours and that the hash value has a random like distribution, you will get a different colour for each hostname, or at least most of them.

Answer (score 0):

to support random color automaticly when using `color` without argument

add the following lines to `~/.profile` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
PRELINE="\r\033[A"

function random {
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;$((1 + $RANDOM % 255))\a"$PRELINE
}

function color {
    case $1 in
    green)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;57\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;197\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;77\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    red)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;270\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;60\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;83\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    orange)
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;red;brightness;227\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;green;brightness;143\a"$PRELINE
    echo -e "\033]6;1;bg;blue;brightness;10\a"$PRELINE
    ;;
    *)
    random
    esac
}

#color    #uncomment to enable automatically set random color when tab created
```

After each time a new iterm2 tab created, use command `color` to automaticly give it a new/random color.

if you want the iterm2-tab color set automatically whenever it is created, then .just add `color` to then end of `.zshrc` / `.profile` or just after the `function color`

On `Host 1`. the `color` line change to `color red`;
On `host 2`. the `color` line chang to `color blue`;
etc.
If more host, just add more color settings like in the example.

Then, each time ,you open the corresponding host ssh terminal, the tab color changes as you want.